# Non-compact dynamical systems

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, descriptive-set-theory, topological-dynamics

In topological dynamics, most of the time, we consider the continuous action of a (semi)group $G$ on a compact Hausdorff space $X$. In this context, we can envelop the group in a compact left topological semigroup $E(G,X)$ (the pointwise closure of $G$ in $X^X$) which gives us e.g. the existence of minimal ideals and idempotents within them.

I was wondering, is there some useful theory like this when $X$ is not necessarily compact? I suppose in any case, $E(G,X)$ is a left topological semigroup and not much more can be shown if $G$ and $X$ are arbitrary, but maybe something along the lines of the following hypotheses would help:

1. $X$ is a complete, separable metric space and $G$ consists of uniform homeomorphisms (the inverses are also uniformly continuous).
2. Like 1., but $X$ is an arbitrary Hausdorff complete uniform space.
3. In addition to 1. or 2., $X$ is locally compact.

I suppose you could show quite a lot if $X$ is a disjoint union of compact $G$-spaces, but I am mostly interested in the case when the action is point-transitive.